# Git log format with branches but without tags?

Tags: git, logging, format, branch

I'd like to show `git log` with all branch names but without tags (since in my repo there is a lot of them which obstruct the view)

I am using the following formatting:

```
git log --all --decorate --oneline --color --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset - %s %C(yellow)%d%Creset %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit
```

which has a problem with this yellow bit - it lists both tags and branches.

From https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats

> '%d': ref names, like the --decorate option of git-log[1]
>
> '%D': ref names without the " (", ")" wrapping.

Is there a specific 'formatter' using which I can only list branches?